# Observable does not get a value in template

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular component `isLoading$` Observable depends on counter$ and defines is it data loading:

```
export class MediaQueriesWidgetComponent implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  // ... some code 

  isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;
  counter$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private _ApiService: ApiService) {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { 
    this.counter$ = merge(
      this.url$.pipe(mapTo(1)),
      this.cssInternal$.pipe(mapTo(1)),
      this.css$.pipe(mapTo(-1)),
    ).pipe(
      scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0),
    );

    this.isLoading$ = this.counter$.pipe(map(counter => counter !== 0))

    //  ... some code
  }
}
```

An issue with `isLoading$` binding does not get a value  in template while data was actually retrieved. Naturally, it causes moving to template's `else` section:

```
  <span> {{ isLoading$ | async }} </span>  // empty span
 <div class="list-container" *ngIf="!(isLoading$ | async); else loading"></div>
 <ng-template #loading></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove !(not) operator in ngIf.

```
<div class="list-container" *ngIf="(isLoading$ | async); else loading">
  Loading from If
</div>
<ng-template #loading> Loading from else</ng-template>
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grtalt